# no more postback after file download in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

After downloading a file from a webpage, I can't do anything on that page. It is like the page is not working anymore. When I click on other button, there is no post back.

Here are my codings.

```
filename= "test.txt"
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + fileName);
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName));
Response.End();
```

So I try to comment **Response.End()** but it is still not working.

What can be the possible problems?

**UPDATE**

[Go to this link to see how I solved it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749393/no-more-post-back-after-file-download-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Why there is a down vote ?
just curious.