# Image download from browser

Tags: asp.net, html, http

I have a problem downloading an image from a web browser.  I want to download the image directly, but instead it's opened in the browser. I'm using asp.net.

My HTML code:

```
<a href ="http://example.com/file/image.jpg" target="_blank" /> Download </a>
```

Comment: Related answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631110/no-more-postback-after-file-download-in-asp-net/7631182#7631182

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do here is to modify the HTTP headers to in a way that requests the browser to show the "File Dialog" box for your image instead of simply displaying it on screen.

To do this you need to modify the `Content-Disposition` header and set it to `attachment`.  To do this in ASP.NET you can do the following:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefilename")
```

but make sure you do this **before** you respond with the file.

You might also want to change the following:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
```

This will allow the browser to regonise and display the image icon in the File Dialog box.  To finally send the file you would then call:

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/myimage.jpg"));
Response.End();
```

However please realise all you are doing here is modifying what the server requests of the browser - it is not bound in anyway carry it out.

Comment: To add on to this answer - in order to get to this code, you'll have to put it in an ASHX handler (or you could use an empty ASPX page, but ASHX is better suited). So instead of your link pointing to `image.jpg`, it would point to `image.ashx`, and m.edmondson's code would be in the .ashx.cs file. (PS I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method (assuming you're using c#)

```
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myimage.jpg");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/images/image.jpg"));
    Response.End();
```