# No more post back after file download in sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, download

I tried to download a file from sharepoint.
But after I download this file, I can't click on other buttons.
What is wrong with my coding?

**This is my first way.**

> ```
>             Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + fileName);
>             Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
>             Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName));
>             Response.End();
> ```

**This is my second way**

> ```
>             byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\" + fileName);
>
>             Response.ClearContent();
>             Response.ClearHeaders();
>             Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
>             Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
>
>             Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + fileName);
>
>             Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
>             Response.Flush();
>             Response.End();
> ```

I even comment Response.End() but still the same result.

Is there any other way I should tried?

Any help would be really appreciated.
In fact, I posted this question a few days ago, but only one gave me my second way to try but it is still not working.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is my GridView under GridView.

```
           <asp:GridView ID="gvGiro" Width="100%" runat="server" GridLines="Both" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="form-table" ShowHeader="false"
                AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvGiro_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblValueDate" Text='<%# getDate(Eval("ValueDate")) %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:GridView ID="gvDetail" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" 
                                CssClass="list-table border" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sequence Number" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        ItemStyle-Width="30%" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["MessageSeqNbr"] %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Number of Debit Transaction" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["TotalDebitNbr"] %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="25%"
                                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["CodeDesc"] %>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidCode" runat="server" Value='<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Code"] %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%"
                                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" CssClass="button submit" Text="Download" 
                                CommandName="download" OnCommand="onCmd" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Width="80px"/>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUnbatch" runat="server" CssClass="button generic" Text="Un-Batch"
                                CommandName="unbatch" OnCommand="onCmd" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Width="80px"/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my cs file

```
    protected void gvGiro_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gr;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            gr = (GridView) e.Row.FindControl("gvDetail");
            using (class2 ct2= new Class2())
            {
                Label lblValueDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblValueDate");
                DateTime dt= DateTime.MinValue;
                DataSet ds= ct2.GetData(dt);
                gr.DataSource = ds; 
                gr.DataBind();

            }

        }
    }


protected void onCmd(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string id;
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "unbatch":
                id= e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                Unbatch(id);
                break;
            case"download":
                id= e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                Download(id);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void Download(string id)
    {
        // to do - substitute all hard-code guid
        Guid batchId = new Guid(id);
        string fileName = "";
        Class1 ct = new Class1();


        {
            if (!ct.FileExists(batchId , ref fileName))
            {
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\" + fileName);
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + fileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            }
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by you can't click other buttons? You mean the other buttons in the browser?

Comment: Yes. The other buttons are there. They don't work after this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SharePoint registers a JavaScript "on submit" handler. In this handler the global variable `_spFormOnSubmitCalled` is set to `true`. SharePoint uses this variable to check if a submit was executed and prevents any further submits. Since your "download postback" does not refresh the page this variable remains `true`. With the effect that that all other buttons stop working.

As a workaround you can set this variable to false in a client click handler on your download button:

```cs
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "Download";
btn.Click += DownloadButton_Click;

// set the client click handler
btn.OnClientClick = "window.setTimeout(function() { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 10);"
```

Of course thats a little hacky and is not garantueed to work in upcoming SharePoint versions.

Comment: I am trying to use your way. But unfortunately, I use onCommand for this button and those buttons are inside a GridView.
When I try to substitue btn.Click+=DownloadButton_Click with btn.Command = onCmd, it does not work.

Comment: can you post the code which creates the button or the grid view?

Comment: Thx for ur help, in fact, it's GridView inside GridView. I will update in my question.

Comment: Adding the `OnClientClick` handler in the asp does not work? => `<asp:Button ... CommandName="download" OnCommand="onCmd" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' OnClientClick="window.setTimeout(function() { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 10);"  ...  />`

Comment: it works perfectly now !!!
Thx a lot !!!
You are awesome, it took about 4 hours from me before u help me!!

Comment: -> hi again !! One question, after downloading, I would like to disable the download button on the gridview. So I call gv.DataBind(). It does not work. What can the my problem? I even comment Response.End(). Same result.

Answer (score 9):

There is an easy way to work around this.
Register OnClientClick event for the button click and set _spFormOnSubmitCalled to false.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:setFormSubmitToFalse()" />
```

And put the script below in the page/js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFormSubmitToFalse() {
        _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;        
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had no success using '_spFormOnSubmitCalled'. I did have success by placing this in my Page_Load function.

```
string js = @"_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true;";
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "js", js, true);
```

[Ajax second postback not working in Sharepoint in UpdatePanel](http://www.marten-online.com/sharepoint/ajax-second-postback-not-working-in-sharepoint-in-updatepanel.html) Provides some background information as to why this is needed.

Comment: this worked for me while changing the _spFormOnSubmitCalled didn't so +1 and thanks for saving my day

Comment: You saved my day buddy! (I just added this code to my aspx page and it worked like a charm: _spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true)

Comment: Thanks flip.. tried lots of tricks but only yours work for me :-)...thanks again

Answer (score 1):

there's an even easier solution to all of this. Instead of a download button simply use an

`<a>`

I usually use something like:

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("{0}",BuildUrl(Eval("Title")))%>' title='<%#Eval("Title") %>'>Download</a>
```

Comment: In BuildUrl , I should write the download coding ?

Comment: yep, thats exactly what you should do. I usually make a reference to a utility class where I do this but you can also do it in the code behind of your user control.

Answer (score 1):

I am using SharePoint 2010 and DexExpress and inside my visual webpart all I needed to add was the clientSideEvents portion. below is my code...

```
<dx:ASPxButton 
    runat="server" 
    ID="btnExportGrid" 
    Text="Export Data" 
    AutoPostBack="False"  
  OnClick="btnExportGrid_Click" Theme="Office2010Blue" Width="140px"    
  CausesValidation="False"  >
      <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {_spFormOnSubmitCalled=false;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true; }" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

and my C# code

```
protected void btnExportGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  gridExporter.WriteXlsToResponse();   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys haven't seen [using-asp-net-ajax-with-sharepoint-moss-2007](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/01/19/using-asp-net-ajax-with-sharepoint-moss-2007.aspx) yet it explains the problem beautifully.  There are better solutions here though.  Thanks to @SSK this was the correct pointer in the right direction that I couldn't have done it without.

But in SP2013 at least there is a function for resetting _spFormOnSubmitCalled to false already so no need to write your own.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:_spResetFormOnSubmitCalledFlag()"></asp:LinkButton>
```

[image]