# Generate a file for download on button click - without breaking other buttons

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, webforms

I'm trying to provide an option to download a report (in csv format), allowing the user to select a specific date range. (I also have an option to display the same information in a GridView on the page). I can do this just fine by using Response.Clear(), setting the ContentType and content-disposition, using Response.Write(), and then Response.End(), like [this blog](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/creating-downloadable-content-dynamically), and many others.

However, after doing this, the buttons no longer seem to be posting back to the server. I can update my report in the GridView however many times I like, but as soon as I export neither button will respond (i.e. no further server side events are generated). How can I get a file and keep the buttons respoding? This is on a SharePoint application page, so there's a bunch of stuff going on in a Master page.

Comment: Throwing similar code into a plain ASP.Net file works fine, so it's probably something SharePoint is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I found an answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749393/no-more-post-back-after-file-download-in-sharepoint)

SharePoint registers a variable called "_spFormOnSubmitCalled" which will prevent any postbacks once it is set to true. I've added an OnClientClick to my button to set it back to false after a short delay, as in Stefan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
Had a form with a grid and a button that was supposed to export the grid to an excel sheet.

Using this piece of javascript within the markup fixed it for me:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  _spOriginalFormAction = document.forms[0].action;
  _spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

asp code :

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">    
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" HeaderStyle BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true" OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "CustomerID" HeaderText ="CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "City" HeaderText = "City"/
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "Country" HeaderText = "Country"/>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "PostalCode" HeaderText = "PostalCode"/>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
  <br />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ExportToCSV" OnClick="btnExportCSV_Click" />
   </form>

Protected void btnExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        //add separator
        sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
    }
    //append new line
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: are you doing response.flush??

Comment: I did not originally have buffer/flush, I do now, no difference.